# Words meaning changing from good to better

Tags: word-request

I am looking for verbs that can mean changing from good to better. "improve" can means changing from bad to less bad, so I am hesitant to use it.

For example, my presentation skills have been __ through my teaching assistant duties.

By the way, are there references that help with similar questions?

Thanks!

Comment: How do you feel about “refined”, “enhanced”, or “developed”? Also, you might consider writing it without “been” and see if it sounds like a stronger statement.

Answer (score 8):

A very common metaphorical usage for OP's context is...

> *My presentation skills have been [**honed**](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/hone) by my teaching assistant duties*.
>
> **Hone**, the verb, literally means to sharpen with a hone, a whetstone used to sharpen cutting tools. Use hone to describe someone working hard, perfecting or sharpening skills, as in *"She is honing her skills as an actress by working in community theater."*

Comment: I have thought about that. But I was wondering if it is too informal, because of the metaphorical usage?

Comment: @Tim: If you look at at some of these 2600 written instances of ["skills have been honed"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22skills+have+been+honed%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), I think you'll agree many of them are quite formal contexts. Any "informality" in your context derives primarily from the fact that formal usage tends to avoid the implied "self-aggrandisement" *(my skills were already **good**, but they became **even better**)*. But since you specifically want to make that point, you can at least console yourself by knowing that *honed* is better than, say, *perfected*.

Comment: @Tim: If you had already thought about that before asking the question, I wish you had mentioned it in the question. _"What's a good word for 'improve'?"_ is a pretty straightforward question answerable with a good thesaurus. On the other hand, _"Is 'hone' too metaphorical a word to use for 'improve' in a formal context?"_ is an interesting poser that would have garnered an immediate upvote from me. (The short answer is: "No, the word 'hone' is just fine in that context," but explaining **why** would be a challenging task.)

Comment: @Tim Until I read this answer, I had no idea that *hone* was a reference to an actual tool. I may or may not be in the minority among native speakers on that point, but I don't think the fact that it's derived from a physical action makes it more informal (for example, *sharpened* also comes from a physical action, but isn't overly informal because of it). I think *honed* is an excellent choice of word in this context. (+1!)